# Error : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

this is a part code file app.js

```
....
this.state = {
      todoList: [
        { id: 1, name: "Khoa" },
        { id: 2, name: "Linh" },
        { id: 3, name: "Luc" },
      ],
      inputText: "",
      currentName: "",
      todoSearch : []
    };
  }
....
handleSubmit = (e, inputRef) => {
    const { todoList, currentName } = this.state;
    if (inputRef.current.value.trim() === "")
      alert("Hay nhap du lieu can input");
    else {
      if (currentName !== "") {
         this.setState({
           todoList : todoList.map(item => {
             if(item.name === currentName) {
               return {...item, name : inputRef.current.value}// error this code
             }
           }),
           currentName : ''
         })
      } else {
        const data = { id: todoList.length + 1, name: inputRef.current.value };
        console.log("say hi");
        this.setState({
          todoList: [...todoList, data],
          currentName : ''
        });
      }
    }
  };
.....
```

> I want to update data unsatisfactorily item.name === currentName . Meaning replace name old of object in todoList equal new name is inputRef.current.value but not work. help me

Comment: oh, sorry i am edited my posted please check them

Comment: In your `map`, only objects with `item.name === currentName` is updated. Rest of the objects are set to undefined because you are not returning anything. Try adding `else return item` to that `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Put else if the value doesn't match -

```
todoList : todoList.map(item => {
         if(item.name === currentName) {
           return {...item, name : inputRef.current.value}// error this code
         }else{
           return {...item}
       })
```

Comment: @KhoaVõĐức please upvote and approve if that helped you

Comment: @KhoaVõĐức If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left. You can also upvote it by clicking on the up arrow button. (I'm only mentioning it because you have not accepted any answers till date)